# Prevent Lead Owners to Transfer leads

Tags: leads

How can i prevent the lead owners to change the ownership of the lead. Why they are able to transfer ownership in the same role and not anyone else like System Admin

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a lead trigger to intercept on 'before update' and process those where ownerid field is changing. Then evaluate whether you want to allow transfer or not. If you dont use .addError method to enforce a stop on the action.